# How to save the UI View or UI Screen in onStop()?

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, gallery, android-lifecycle

I have a gallery app. In which I have used `RecycylerView` to show photos. I want to save the content of UI whenever user leaves the app in `onStop()` and restore the same content whenever the user opens app again in `onCreate()`. In short I want to eliminate image loading , show the previous UI and then after I can load images in background. So, User won't see image placeholders. And will feel that images are loaded instantly.

**Example**

Suppose you are using Instagram. You pressed home button and navigated to WhatsApp. Sent some messages and came back to Instagram. You found that your screen looks the same. Because when `onPause()` event was triggered OS saved the UI state. (I don't exactly know what android OS will save when `onPause()` is triggered.) And restored the same when `onResume()` Event is triggered.

The same is happening with my app even I am not saving anything at all in `onPause()`. So, I want to save that data or UI state in `onStop()` which is being saved in `onPause()` by OS. And want to restore the same in `onCreate()`.

**What I have Tried**

I tried to save the state of `RecyclerView` in `onStop()` and restoring it whenever the `adapter` is attached.

```
...
 @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        State = layoutManager.onSaveInstanceState();
    }

    ...
     adapter = new PhotosAdapter(requireActivity().getApplicationContext(), arrayList, getActivity(), this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        layoutManager.onRestoreInstanceState(State);
...
```

But, this didn't work. I had issue that if user is in the middle of `RecyclerView` and presses home button and then gets back to app `RecyclerView` will be shown from top and user has to scroll again to middle. So, I found that saving state in `onPause()` solves the issue. So, I thought it might be saving the whole `layoutManager`. And tried it to save it in `onStop()`. But, as expected it didn't work.

I know that overriding `onSaveInstanceState()` can help. But, Here it's not about int,string or any data type. I want to save whatever is on the screen in `onStop()` and whatever data is saved by OS in `onPause()`. And finally want to restore that data in `onCreate()`.

Please Guide me to further steps.

Comment: What are you using to show the images? With libraries like glide or picasso you can explicit choose to use the app cache or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to save the values in savedInstanceState and try to restore it.
As official documentation suggests to use `ViewModel` as well to store the complex data.

> To bridge the gap between user expectation and system behavior, use a combination of ViewModel objects, the onSaveInstanceState() method, and/or local storage to persist the UI state across such application and activity instance transitions. Deciding how to combine these options depends on the complexity of your UI data, use cases for your app, and consideration of speed of retrieval versus memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

Quick solution: Create a class called `LastSavedState.java` or anything and have it implement `Parcelable`. During `onPause()`, put everything you want to save inside and put it into Bundle using `setArguments(Bundle)` or `setIntent(Intent)` if you are using Activity. During `onResume()` you can get your state back using `getArguments()` or `getIntent()` and set everything back to where you left.

Recommend Solution: Your app should follow an android architecture like MVI or MVVM and have a State for each screen so your view model or presenter can save and restore the State during `onPause()`/`onResume()`

Comment: I am saving the necessary details during `onPause()` and restoring during `onResume()`. But, I want to save UI during `onStop()` and restore it during `onCreate()` after user closed the app, cleared it from recent apps and reopened app.

Comment: And I don't know what to save to preserve the UI. I explained my scenario and what I want to save. But, I don't know what should I save to preserve the last showed view in code.

Comment: You need to read more about activities lifecycles

Comment: What you need is different from what you ask, you want to preserve the UI even after users have closed and cleared your app? Then your options are to either save everything to local storage or repository and load them back whenever users re-open your app.

Comment: @javdromero went through android's officaial documentation and It was helpful. But, there they mentioned saving datatypes like string , int in bundle. But I want to know that what data should I save and how to save it.

Comment: @Brown I clearly mentioned that I want to save data during `onStop()` and want to load that data during `onCreate()` when user opens the app again. And yes I have to store the data in local storage or repository. But, what data should I save? and how do I save that data to loacal storage or repository? that's the problem.